# native client filesystem, different domain access same file

Tags: google-nativeclient

For example,on website *www.A.com*,I use native client filesystem,and save a File named file1.txt. And on website www.B.com, i access the same pexe by using CORS.But the website www.B.com create its own file.Not the same one on website www.A.com. And on my local computer, I find out in the \Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\File System  directory, there are two directories named *001* and *002*, obviously, they are created by www.A.com and www.B.com.I want to know how to share file between www.A.com and www.B.com

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to use CORS mechanism in native client](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28781808/how-to-use-cors-mechanism-in-native-client)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've found, the Pepper Filesystem (which is equivalent to the JavaScript DOMFilesystem) is per-origin to the module embedder, not the origin of the pexe. There is no way direct way to share the file.

One possible workaround is to embed your pexe using an iframe. That way it would always use the filesystem origin of the iframe.